# How can I pass a reference of `this` to children using functional components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working to convert some class based code over to functional (and learning functional react along the way).

I know that I can pass references to individual variables of a component function as props to children, but is there a `<Child parentPage={this} />` equivalent when using functional components?

The idea being that then a child component could call `this.props.parentPage.updateValue()`, instead of needing to do `this.props.updateValue()`. I realize that's actually more work in a simple parent -> child relationship, but when you find yourself a few generations deep, with siblings and cousins all needing to access `this.props.parentPage.*`.

Comment: what does the original code is tryig to achieve? can you post an example of the one of this class based components as well?

Comment: Sounds like a context would fit your use case if you need to share/access an object several layers deep

Comment: Is a context a good usecase for this? Defining vars (which are functions) that update the parentPage state (for example), and passing them into a context to be shared? My context knowledge is weak here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to avoid prop drilling. Without knowing the details of your code, it's hard to say what the best solution would be, but most likely you could [use context for this](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

Other than that, you could [extract components and pass JSX as children to them](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#before-you-use-context). Or just keep passing the props, sometimes that's fine.

Comment: Yah, alright so it sounds like the answer to my question is that there isn't an equivalent to `this` when using functional components. Either using a context, prop drilling, or passing JSX in as props are the three preferred methods when using functional components

Comment: To my knowledge, yes.